# What's the most sparse block-diagonalization you can do with unitary equivalence?

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is, in general, what is the simplest form (most sparse and/or smallest diagonal blocks) an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ can be put in if we are allowed only unitary equivalence

$$A = U B U^{-1}$$

where $B$ is "simple" and $U$ is unitary? We know that if $U$ is allowed to be any invertible matrix then $B$ can have Jordan normal form. We also know that if $U$ is unitary then $B$ can be made upper triangular. Can we do any better?

Comment: Regarding overall sparsity, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/588464/81360). Indeed, it seems that upper-triangularization is the best that we can do.

Answer (score 1):

The reference given by Omno is an excellent one.

In complex case, we can also reason as follows. We are dealing with REAL algebraic sets, with real dimensions $dim(M_n(\mathbb{C})=2n^2,dim(U_n)=n^2$. Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a GENERIC matrix (for example, randomly choose it).

We consider the trajectory under the action $U\in U_n\mapsto UAU^*$; this trajectory contains a triangular matrix; that is one has at most $n^2+n$ real parameters in such a representation.  Assume that we can do better, that is, we can obtain representations with at most $n^2+n-k$ real parameters. Note that here one has a finite number of entries. Then we can write the equality

$2n^2=(n^2+n-k)+n^2-dim(C(A))$ where $C(A)$ is the algebraic set $\{U\in U_n;AU=UA\}$. Clearly, when $A$ is generic, $C(A)=\{e^{i\theta}I_n;\theta\in\mathbb{R}\}$ has real dimension $1$. Thus the maximum value for $k$ is $n-1$.

$\textbf{Conclusion.}$ Roughly speaking, this means that we can choose in our triangular representation at most $n-1$ locations where the entries are real (for example). In fact, we can really do that as follows

Let our triangular representation be $T=[t_{i,j}]$ with $t_{k,k}=\lambda_k,t_{k-1,k}=\rho_ke^{i\theta_k}$ (polar form).

Then $Te_k=\lambda_ke_k+\rho_ke^{i\theta_k}e_{k-1}+\cdots$. We change $e_k$ with $f_k=e^{-i\theta_k}e_k$.

Then $Tf_k=\lambda_kf_k+\rho e_{k-1}+\cdots$. By iterating this method, the false diagonal $(i,i+1)$ -with $n-1$ elements- becomes real($\geq 0$).

Comment: This is a very nice approach, explained very cleanly. The idea of working along the superdiagonal is much easier to get a feeling for than the approach taken in the post I linked.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom , thanks. That is funny is that we cannot annihilate simultaneously  the real part and the imaginary part of one same entry in the triangle (even if $n$ is large).